# If two balls are drawn at random, find the probability of second drawn being red if the first drawn was blue.

Tags: probability

I am quoting the objective question which I got today in my online exam.

> A box has 6 red and 9 blue balls. If two balls are drawn at random, find the probability of second drawn being red if the first drawn was blue.

I applied conditional probability and arrived at the answer 9/35 but it did not match with any of the given options.

Comment: What calculations did you perform to get $\dfrac{9}{35}$?  How many red balls are there?  $6$ red balls?  Or $9$ red balls?  You used the word red twice and did not use the word blue yet.  Assuming it were $6$ blue and $9$ red balls... other than semantics what is the difference between your original question and the question "*A box has $5$ blue and $9$ red balls.  One ball is drawn at random.  What is the probability of it being red?*"

Comment: Did you mean $6$ red and $9$ blue balls or $6$ blue and $9$ red balls?  Also, you should show how you arrived at your answer since that it makes easier for users of this site to detect any errors you may have made.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: You have corrected the typo.  You have not yet expanded upon or provided more information or calculations on how you arrived at $\dfrac{9}{35}$.  You should do that.

Comment: @JMoravitz Sorry Sir for the mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: @JMoravitz The probability of drawing a blue ball first is 9/15. After drawing the blue ball, 14 more balls are left. So, the probability of drawing a red ball is now 6/14. By multiplication theorem, I arrived at the answer 9/35.

Comment: Why would you multiply?  This is a *given that such and such*.  Do not confuse $P(A\cap B)$ with $P(A\mid B)$.  The answer they were looking for was just the $6/14$ you stated in "*So, the probability of drawing a red ball is now 6/14.*"  The question "what is the probability that the second ball is red **and** the first ball is blue" is different than the question "what is the probability that the second ball is red **given that** the first ball is blue"

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you Sir. I get my mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: after the first ball is drawn, given that it is blue, how many balls of each colour remain in the box?